# What's the group of words that should exist but don't even though other words suggest that they do?

Tags: terminology

(Please redirect me to https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/ if that's a better forum for this question)

There are certain pairs of words where the opposite word is suggested but sometimes doesn't exist. This mainly deals with word endings such as ful and less. For instance, powerful exists and, therefore, it's safe to assume powerless exists. However, sometimes the corresponding word doesn't actually exist. (wonderful/wonderless may be an example of this)

I've tried googling this, but it's a difficult concept to put into searchable terms.

Comment: It's possible [to have a lot of fun](https://www.ling.upenn.edu/~beatrice/humor/how-i-met-my-wife.html) with such un-negations.

Comment: Wonderless has at least [one dictionary definition](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/wonderless)

Comment: @Laurel Ooh, I like "absent antonyms." Sounds like something you should be able to bring a lawsuit for.